# capturing group of consecutive digits using regex

Tags: java, regex

i'm trying to capture only the two 6's adjacent to each other and get how many times did it occur using regex like if we had `794234879669786694326666976` the answer should be 2 or if its 66666 it should be zero and so on i'm using the following code and captured it by this `(66)*` and using `matcher.groupcount()` to get how many times did it occur but its not working !!!

```
package me;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class blah {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       // Define regex to find the word 'quick' or 'lazy' or 'dog'
    String regex = "(66)*";
    String text = "6678793346666786784966";

    // Obtain the required matcher
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    int match=0;

    int groupCount = matcher.groupCount();
    System.out.println("Number of group = " + groupCount);

    // Find every match and print it
    while (matcher.find()) {

        match++;
    }
    System.out.println("count is "+match);
}

}
```

Comment: If you don't have a requirement to use regular expressions, I'd recommend to solve it programmatically, by using an old-fashioned loop. It will be easier to understand and faster by some orders of magnitude.

Comment: i tried to but it's way harder than you imagine there will always be a bug or a test case that won't work @Ralf Kleberhoff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach here would be to use lookarounds to ensure that you match *only* islands of exactly two sixes:

```
String regex = "(?<!6)66(?!6)";
String text = "6678793346666786784966";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
```

This finds a count of two, for the input string you provided (the two matches being the `66` at the very start and end of the string).

The regex pattern uses two lookarounds to assert that what comes before the first 6 and after the second 6 are *not* other sixes:

```
(?<!6)   assert that what precedes is NOT 6
66       match and consume two 6's
(?!6)    assert that what follows is NOT 6
```

Comment: thank you it works perfectly but i still could't understand the regex patter!

Comment: @Ahmad, see [my explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55656476/capturing-group-of-consecutive-digits-using-regex/55656896#55656896) above.  I use lookarounds to make sure that we only match `66` in case where no other 6's come before or after.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
String regex = "(?<!6)66(?!6)";
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3QHER6/2).

[image]

**Details**

- `(?<!6)` - no `6` right before the current location
- `66` -  `66`  substring
- `(?!6)` - no `6` right after the current location.

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/UrxExY):

```
String regex = "(?<!6)66(?!6)";
String text = "6678793346666786784966";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
int match=0;
while (matcher.find()) {
    match++;
}
System.out.println("count is "+match); // => count is 2
```

Answer (score 0):

This didn't take long to come up with.  I like regular expressions but I don't use them unless really necessary.  Here is one loop method that appears to work.

```
  char TARGET = '6';
  int GROUPSIZE = 2;
  // String with random termination character that's not a TARGET
  String s = "6678793346666786784966" + "z";

  int consecutiveCount = 0;
  int groupCount = 0;
  for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
     if (c == TARGET) {
        consecutiveCount++;
     }
     else {
        // if current character is not a TARGET, update group count if
        // consecutive count equals GROUPSIZE
        if (consecutiveCount == GROUPSIZE) {
           groupCount++;
        }
        // in any event, reset consecutive count
        consecutiveCount = 0;
     }
  }

  System.out.println(groupCount);
```